# How does calling one function set the variable of another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I came across this while watching a video and though they did a good job explaining closures, they did not really explain how the functions were linked. So, I still did not understand how calling newFunction('inside') somehow set the values for both outerVariable and innerVariable. Can anyone explain how this works? Here's the code:

```
function outerFunction(outerVariable){
    return function innerFunction(innerVariable) {
        console.log('Outer Variable ' + outerVariable)
        console.log('Outer Variable ' + innerVariable)

    }
}

const newFunction = outerFunction('outside')
newFunction('inside')
```

Comment: *"how calling newFunction('inside') somehow set the values for both outerVariable and innerVariable"*: calling `newFunction` does not set the value for the `outerVariable`. That variable was set by calling `outerFunction`, and is still available to `innerFunction` whenever it gets called.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. And how does newFunction set innerVariable?

Comment: `innerVariable` is set when `newFunction` is called. `newFunction` refers to the *same* function that `innerFunction` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
newFunction('inside')
```

does not set outerVariable. What happens here is a classic javascript closure.
A closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function.

In this case:

```
const newFunction = outerFunction('outside')
```

will return a new function (in our case its innerFunction) and innerFunction when called will have access to its to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In this case, our surrounding state is outerVariable variable.

So basically, at this point its similar to this:

```
var outerVariable = "outside"
function innerFunction(innerVariable) {
        console.log('Outer Variable ' + outerVariable)
        console.log('Outer Variable ' + innerVariable)

    }
```

And when you call innerFunction with "inside", ofc innerVariable will be "inside" and outerVariable will have a value of "outside".

Comment: Much clearer now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic closure.
when you called the `outerFunction` in this line:
`const newFunction = outerFunction('outside')`

`newFunction` saved `innerFunction` as the return value. The principle of closure makes sure that newFunction also received all the execution context of `innerFunction` along with it.
Which means that it receives the variable  `outerVariable` which has the values `outside` that got passed to it in the above line.
Thats how it can print not only `innerVariable` which you passed while invoking `newFunction` but also the value of `outerVariable`.